# Existence of a holomorphic function such that...

Tags: complex-analysis

For $D$ the open unit disk in the complex plane and $f: D \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ holomorphic and $1-1$, does there exist a holomorphic function $g: D\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$ such that $d^2=f'$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $g^2 = f$?

Comment: Nope, $f'$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

1) as $f$ is holomorphic and bijective, it is biholomorphic ;

2) if $f$ is biholomorphic, then $f'$ never vanishes ;

3) you can show that $f'(\mathrm D)$ is simply connected. As it is also not containing zero, there exists a well-defined square-root function on $f'(\mathrm D)$.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I was looking for, I didn't know about biholomorphic functions.

Comment: I was writing it out properly and I just noticed: $f$ is not bijective, it's only injective, so it's not biholomorphic.

Comment: We don't care, injective implies bijective on the image.

Comment: Oh right, we're talking about $f(D)$ not $\Bbb{C}$. I think I got it the first time I read it but when I did today I got confused, sorry.